# Background image not covering web page background

Tags: html, css

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
    
  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

        .navbar {
            background-color: #000000;
            border-color: 1px solid #000000;
        }

        .card-box {
            border-radius: 2.5rem;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top:25px;
            background-color: #000000b0;
            box-shadow:  1px 1px 5px 1px grey;
        }

        .portfolio-item {
            /* height: 250px; */
            text-align: center;
        }

        .row {
            margin: 0px;
        }

        h3 {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .app_rstudio, .app_rstudio-super {
            margin-left: 15%;
        }

        .fa, .far, .fas, .fab {
            font-size: 96px;
            color: #55b0ff;
            margin: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head lang="en">
    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{${bootstrapCss}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/css/default.css}"/>
    <script th:src="@{${jqueryJs}}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{${bootstrapJs}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/2Ww4xTB/background.png" id="bg" alt="">

    <div th:replace="../fragments/navbar :: navbar"></div>

    <div class="container" id="applist">
        <div class="row" >
            <div th:each="app: ${apps}">
                <div th:class="${'col-md-4 portfolio-item app_' + app.id}">
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <a th:href="@{/app/}+${app.id}">
                            <i th:class="${app.logoURL}"></i>
                        </a>
                        <h3>
                            <a th:href="@{/app/}+${app.id}" th:text="${app.displayName == null} ? ${app.id} : ${app.displayName}" style="color: #55b0ff;"></a>
                        </h3>
                        <a th:if="${app.description != null}" th:href="@{/app_direct/}+${app.id + '/'}" style="color: #55b0ff; font-style: italic;" target="_blank">
                            <p th:text="${app.description}"></p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I added the following CSS code to my HTML document:

```css
    body {
            background-color: #333;
            background-image: url(/assets/img/background.png);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: scroll;
            background-position: top center;
            color: rgb(202, 202, 202);
        }
```

But the image does not fill the browser window as expected. Where did I go wrong?

Here is the entire HTML code (probably more than you need but I'm not sure which bits are relevant):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head lang="en">
    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{${bootstrapCss}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/css/default.css}"/>
    <script th:src="@{${jqueryJs}}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{${bootstrapJs}}"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #333;
            background-image: url(/assets/img/background.png);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: scroll;
            background-position: top center;
            color: rgb(202, 202, 202);
        }

        .navbar {
            background-color: #000000;
            border-color: 1px solid #000000;
        }

        .card-box {
            border-radius: 2.5rem;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top:25px;
            background-color: #000000b0;
            box-shadow:  1px 1px 5px 1px grey;
        }

        .portfolio-item {
            /* height: 250px; */
            text-align: center;
        }

        .row {
            margin: 0px;
        }

        h3 {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .app_rstudio, .app_rstudio-super {
            margin-left: 15%;
        }

        .fa, .far, .fas, .fab {
            font-size: 96px;
            color: #55b0ff;
            margin: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div th:replace="../fragments/navbar :: navbar"></div>

    <div class="container" id="applist">
        <div class="row" >
            <div th:each="app: ${apps}">
                <div th:class="${'col-md-4 portfolio-item app_' + app.id}">
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <a th:href="@{/app/}+${app.id}">
                            <i th:class="${app.logoURL}"></i>
                        </a>
                        <h3>
                            <a th:href="@{/app/}+${app.id}" th:text="${app.displayName == null} ? ${app.id} : ${app.displayName}" style="color: #55b0ff;"></a>
                        </h3>
                        <a th:if="${app.description != null}" th:href="@{/app_direct/}+${app.id + '/'}" style="color: #55b0ff; font-style: italic;" target="_blank">
                            <p th:text="${app.description}"></p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried (and failed) to use an approach described [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) which suggests using the following CSS:

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
    
  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

And HTML:

```html
<img src="images/bg.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
```

Comment: Add a snippet to reproduce the issue

Comment: Do you mean a minimally reproducible example? I am working with next to zero knowledge of CSS and HTML.

Comment: Is your body element 100% wide and 100% high? If it doesn't contain enough content it will not fill the entire screen.

Comment: Edit the question, press the <> button and add the code in the relevant sections

Comment: @LelioFaieta Can I move the CSS code between `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>` to the CSS section?

Comment: In order to use the same image I am using, I uploaded it to imgbb.com and inserted the URL in the code snippet. But in my code, I reference the image locally.

Comment: @anatolhiman How would I find out?

Comment: locally u can see ur image, but it's just not full width?

Comment: @J4R If I navigate to the web page (which uses code that references the background image locally), I can see the image but it does not fill the window. I see a grey box at the bottom and on the sides of the image.

Comment: I changed the snippet to use the second approach I described in my question. Now the image appears to fill the window as expected. However, I tried this approach locally and it didn't produce the same results. The only difference is that locally I'm using a local image and here I'm using a URL. Could this be contributing to my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the background will not fill the screen if the device you are using is portrait.

Try adding this to your style:

```
html {
 min-height:100%; 
}
```

Comment: This worked. Also, for those using Docker, don't forget to rebuild image.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to be with your local file path because when adding a url it works fine as seen below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head lang="en">
    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{${bootstrapCss}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/css/default.css}"/>
    <script th:src="@{${jqueryJs}}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{${bootstrapJs}}"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #333;
            background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558481795-7f0a7c906f5e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1373&q=80");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: scroll;
            background-position: top center;
            color: rgb(202, 202, 202);
          width: 100%;
          height: 1600%;
          z-index: -1;
        }

        .navbar {
            background-color: #000000;
            border-color: 1px solid #000000;
        }

        .card-box {
            border-radius: 2.5rem;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top:25px;
            background-color: #000000b0;
            box-shadow:  1px 1px 5px 1px grey;
        }

        .portfolio-item {
            /* height: 250px; */
            text-align: center;
        }

        .row {
            margin: 0px;
        }

        h3 {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .app_rstudio, .app_rstudio-super {
            margin-left: 15%;
        }

        .fa, .far, .fas, .fab {
            font-size: 96px;
            color: #55b0ff;
            margin: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div th:replace="../fragments/navbar :: navbar"></div>

    <div class="container" id="applist">
        <div class="row" >
            <div th:each="app: ${apps}">
                <div th:class="${'col-md-4 portfolio-item app_' + app.id}">
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <a th:href="@{/app/}+${app.id}">
                            <i th:class="${app.logoURL}"></i>
                        </a>
                        <h3>
                            <a th:href="@{/app/}+${app.id}" th:text="${app.displayName == null} ? ${app.id} : ${app.displayName}" style="color: #55b0ff;"></a>
                        </h3>
                        <a th:if="${app.description != null}" th:href="@{/app_direct/}+${app.id + '/'}" style="color: #55b0ff; font-style: italic;" target="_blank">
                            <p th:text="${app.description}"></p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```